# How to search for size in the list and set costing based on it?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to search the 'ITEM NAME' list for matching size and set MRP based on it.

For Example-

NIKE PAHANTOM 38 RED''s MRP needs to be set **320**

NIKE PAHANTOM 44 RED''s MRP needs to be set **400**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `XLOOKUP()` would work:

[image]

---

```
=XLOOKUP(--INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A8," "),3),$B$1:$E$1,$B$2:$E$2,"Not Found")
```

---

Or, if the pattern remains same then using `HLOOKUP()`

```
=HLOOKUP(--MID(A8,14,2),$B$1:$E$2,2,0)
```

---

Or, Using the same method with `HLOOKUP()` and `TEXTSPLIT()`

```
=HLOOKUP(--INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A8," "),3),$B$1:$E$2,2,0)
```

---

Comment: Thank you again, Mayukh.  Since last 2 hours i am trying to figure it out using Vlookup and Hlookup.

Comment: I will, Just waiting for count down to be over.  4 min left.

Comment: I am getting value error in generated MRP field if i change the input size from 38/7. Is there a way to fix it?  Error comes when i use anything other then  a number.

Comment: @ElCalvin quite possible. Try `=XLOOKUP(--INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A8," "),3),--LEFT($B$1:$E$1,2),$B$2:$E$2,"Not Found")`

Comment: It isn't working : (
here is the file
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IZYb1fP4Rn6xZQbDZQD5UxWP9MXldwjT/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100171511867549501133&rtpof=true&sd=true

Comment: @ElCalvin are you excel or Google sheets? If excel what is the version of Excel

Comment: Sorry, File is excel  but since i am sharing file  file via google drive it's opening in google sheets. 

Here the file- 
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9ee49d7c0f954d395b3dd7c469ba484420240329074327/1d6975

Comment: @ElCalvin but what is your version of Excel?

Comment: Version 2402 (Build 17328.20184)

Comment: @ElCalvin download from [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2clAOKtxCgf3hh0yhn?e=ug3j4Y)

Comment: @ElCalvin glad to know it worked!